# Email validation with particular extensions?

Tags: javascript, regex, email, email-validation, email-address

[image]

form code:

```
<form class="form"  name ="custRegistration"  id="custRegistration"  onsubmit="return submitAlbum(this)" action="download.jsp" method="post" >


        <p class="email">
            <label for="budget">Expected Budget :</label>
            <input type="text" name="budget"  id="budget"/>
        </p>




        <p class="submit">
             <label for="download" id="freetrail">Download 30 day free trial</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>

    </form>
```

i want to validate email-ids with the extension which are checked in the above image and block rest of the email-id extensions using javascript..any help would be appreciated??

Comment: What do you mean by validate? JavaScipt can only test if the email address is correctly formatted - not whether the email address is in use or not.

Comment: @jeff am asking the same how to test whether the if the email address is correctly formatted.

Comment: meanwhile in related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(\w+\.)*\w+@(\w+\.)+[A-Za-z]+`

this regex is email check basic.

you may use regex for this case, follow regex:

`((\w+\.)*\w+)@(\w+\.)+(com|kr|net|us|info|biz)`

Answer (score 0):

okay , get all the values of checked items in an array (at least this much you should have been able to do by now)

now let the array be `["com","net"]`

```
var arr = ["com","net"];
var str = arr.join("|")
var re = new RegExp("^\w+@\w+\.("+str+")$");
console.log(re);
```

the regex I have used is the most basic of all, you can change it according to your needs. Another answer on SO suggests `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"` to be a more complete email validator. So you can change your second last line to :

```
var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.("+str+")$");
```

this code will give you the regex you need to validate your email.

Now you can simply do regex `test` to see which emails pass your validation.

happy coding!

Comment: String literals make use of the backslash as the start of an escape sequence. If you want the actual backslash character to be part of the regex you're building, then you need to escape it in the string so that the actual character appears in the resulting string.

Comment: For example: `new RegExp("^\\w+@\\w+\\.("+str+")$")`

Comment: @aelor I suppose you meant `str.join("|")` and not `str` ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon WE JOIN ARRAYS, NOT STRINGS

Comment: @aelor Oh, ok, I did not see that `str` actually had as a value `arr.join("|")`. No need to shout for that I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use above regex ( aelor's )as

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.(COM|ORG|BIZ|CO)
```

include your all extentions using **pipe separator** .